# com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm use javamail in Android get this crash,I don't think the problem is a one-off. Please help me fix this crash,thank you.

javamail version : 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.readResponse(Protocol.java:720)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:695)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.quit(Protocol.java:346)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.close(POP3Folder.java:280)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.finalize(POP3Folder.java:550)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: please post your code so that someone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stacktrace you can see that the finalizer is closing the folder for you.  Make sure your code is [closing folders](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#close-boolean-) before they become unreachable. If you do this then the finalizer call is a no-op. Don't rely on the finalizer to close the folders for you.

Also upgrade to 1.5.6 which changed the way [store finalizers talk to the server](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7472).

Comment: Thank you ,i'm trying use 1.5.6